# jQuery.ajax Response is empty or undefined

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

Hi I hava a big problem. I have to get some JSON form *localhost:8080*.

The server side is a restful based jax-rs server.

```
@Path( "/m" )
public class M {
  @GET
  @Path( "{id: [a-z]{1,4}-\\d{1,4}}" )
  @Produces( "application/json" )
  public Response getCar ( @PathParam( "id" ) final String id ) {
    final ResponseBuilder builder;
    builder = Response.ok( "{\"one\":\"bla\"}" );
    return builder.build();
  }
}
```

For the same origin policy I have the following script on **localhost:8080/js/script.js**

```
function test (file) {
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'GET',
        url: file + '?callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert( 'works' );
        }
    } );
}
```

I don't like the '?callback=?' part, but without this the response is empty (HTTP-Body).

The problem now is, that the success method will never executed. When I change dataType to "script", the method will be called but the passed argument (data) is undefined. So what I do wrong?

Comment: Post your server side code + It's a bad idea to pass two "?" in the params

Comment: The `?callback=?` is correct if you are using JSONP.

Comment: @Byron Cobb, that is correct, but not in this case. The second `?` is used by jQuery to provide a dynamic callback function. It is replaced with that function name before the request is made to the server.

Comment: @Doug - Ah, good to know. This knowledge would have helped me in many previous project. :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test (file) {
    $.getJSON(file + '?callback=?', function(data){
        alert("works");
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay the alert dialog appears but data is null (empty HTTP-Body).
With "?callback=?" I have  a content but the method will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

If your main site is `localhost:80` i.e. `localhost`, even if your calling script is at `:8080` it won't work. It uses the domain/port of the HTML not the external JS files. The reason the `callback=?` might work is because its adding a script element to the page. The important thing is that the JSON on the server supports a callback.

For instance, if it were a PHP script, it would need to do something like this:

```
<?php 
  $json = json_encode(array('key' => "value"));
  echo isset($_GET['callback']) ? $_GET['callback'] . "($json);" : $json;
```

So the resulting output looks like this:

```
callback_function({"key" => "value"});
```

Finally, since you are using JSONP (JSON with a callback), just use `$.getJSON`:

```
$.getJSON(file + '?callback=?', function (data) {
  alert('It Works');
});
```

Comment: the main site is local and the json stuff comes from localhost:8080

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify this and use the getJSON method:

```
function test (file,id) {
$.getJSON(file, {id:id}, function(data){
// do whatever with the returned data array, the id value can be left off if you do not need to reference a particular record.
alert( 'works' );   
});
}
```

I think this will get you what you want to do.

Comment: Judging from his symptoms, it seems like its a cross domain origin policy problem, which is why JSONP kinda worked, but I am betting the server doesn't support the callback.

Comment: the backend is a jax-rs server, so yes maybe there is no callback support.

@Path( "/m" )
public class M {
 @GET
 @Path( "{id: [a-z]{1,4}-\\d{1,4}}" )
 @Produces( "application/json" )
 public Response getCar ( @PathParam( "id" ) final String id ) {
  final ResponseBuilder builder;
  builder = Response.ok( "{\"one\":\"bla\"}" );
  return builder.build();
 }
}

and yes, I know getJSON. But up to know it's just a test.

Answer (score 0):

I create a simple test page on localhost:8080 and it works.

Seems so, I missunderstand the same origin policy problem.